# Why is a data hash returning a compile error in Rails 3.1 and 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am messing around with Railscast #102 Auto-Complete Association in a Rails 3.1 app, which I've just upgraded to 3.2.

When I try to add the data hash to a text field

```
<%= f.text_field :category_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Category.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

Rails generates a compile error, indicating there is a problem with the data hash.

So I rewrote the hash to

```
<%= f.text_field :category_name, 'data-autocomplete_source' => Category.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

This is working, but can someone explain to me if there are any differences between these two approaches that I should be aware off.

Secondly, if I set up the autocomplete function with a static hash of values

```
$(function() {
    $('#post_category_name').autocomplete({
            source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
    });
});
```

The autocomplete works. But if I use the data hash:

```
$(function() {
    $('#post_category_name').autocomplete({
        source: $('#post_category_name').data('autocomplete_source')
    });
});
```

autocomplete is not working? In the console it returns

```
GET http://app.dev/post/4/foo%20food%20four?term=foo 404 (Not Found)
```

This is confusing me, as there are clearly related terms in the GET request. Is this due to my adjusting the data hash, or is something else going on here?

Thanks for your ideas or suggestions to help me learn how all this works.

Comment: Yes, this app is running under REE. Is this the problem? If so I'm using RVM so can switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `symbol: value` JavaScript-ish Hash syntax is new in 1.9 so that explains your first problem. Switching to a 1.9 Ruby or using the traditional syntax:

```
<%= f.text_field :category_name, :data => { :autocomplete_source => Category.order(:name).map(&:name) } %>
```

should take care of that.

Check the generated HTML, I think the data attribute will be `data-autocomplete-source` rather than `data-autocomplete_source` so try this:

```
$('#post_category_name').autocomplete({
    source: $('#post_category_name').data('autocomplete-source')
});
```

Comment: Hi Mu, thanks for your suggestions. If I use `data('autocomplete-source')` I get `Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function` in the console. With `data('autocomplete_source')` I get a valid GET that returns a 404 error. I assumed the name corresponds with the name defined in the data hash. Is this correct? I'd also really appreciate if you could explain a bit more background behind the data hash. What is doing actually, and what is the difference between this and simply writing `'data-autocomplete-source'=> source-data.....`. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: my mistake, you are correct, should be `autocomplete-source`. this is now working great, only think left is to get this working on multiple columns with a splitter!. Thanks for all your help. If you can point me towards more info on the data hash, would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AndyHarvey: Sorry, that's all I know about the data hash. This stuff isn't exactly well documented (or I can't find the documentation), I'm just working from things I've seen in other SO questions.